# Can't get Netbeans to stay locked to launcher?

Tags: launcher, netbeans

I've installed Netbeans [for PHP] which has appeared in a directory in my home folder. To launch the program I keep having to navigate to /home//netbeans-7.1.2/bin/ to run the launcher. Once it's running, if I right-click the icon in the launcher list and click 'Lock to launcher', next time I startup it's gone.

How can I make it stay there so I don't have to run it from Netbeans' bin directory every time?

Comment: what desktop manager?! I found that in some it stays, and in some it doesn't

Comment: Apologies for the noob'ish question, but how do I find out? It's just all on a default Ubuntu 12.04 installation. Thanks.

Comment: I bet ur using unity then?! log out and you can select what desktop manager to use, the default is unity, if you give me a sec I will login with unity and check if there is an netbeans in my launcher.

Comment: ok its called Ubuntu/Ubuntu 2D for me, and it locks in NetBeans, I have no clue why it wouldn't for you, sorry man

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway. Would you mind upvoting the question so it gets a little more attention? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a program called "MainMenu" for this, (I think it is installed by default with 12.04 LTS) if not installed you can install it from the application store.

After loading MainMenu, click the "Add new item" button and follow the screen instructions. So simple.

Comment: Hey Duke, I installed that but it will not add or remove items from my launcher - infact most of the items ticked on there aren't even on my launcher. Any idea why?

Comment: First add Netbeans to the MainMenu, now go to your DashHome and search for Netbeans, now drag the Netbeans icon from the search results and drop it to the launcher.

Comment: Can't award your bounty for 23 hours.

Comment: Seems interesting, Duke. Can you confirm that you mean "MainMenu" as in Alacarte?